# What is Fuseable interface in Reactor project for?

Tags: project-reactor

There are many usages of Fuseable interface in Reactor source code but I can't find any reference what is it. Could someone explain it's purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Fuseable` interface, and its containing interfaces define the contracts used for stream fusion. Stream fusion is a reactive streams optimisation.

Without any such optimisation (in "normal" execution if you will), each reactive operator:

- Subscribes to a previous operator in the chain
- Is notified when the subscriber has completed
- Performs its operation
- Notifies its subscribers

...and then the cycle repeats for all operators. This is fantastic for making sure everything stays non-blocking, but all of those asynchronous calls come with some amount of overhead.

"Stream fusion" (or "operator fusion") significantly reduces this overhead by performing two or more of the operations in one chunk (fusing them together as one unit), passing values between them using a `Queue` or similar rather than via subscriptions, eliminating this overhead. It's not always possible of course - it can't be done this way if running in parallel, when certain side effects come into play, etc. - but a neat optimisation when it is possible.